# Tesseract 2 not reconize simple black text (license plate)

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to create a basic license plate reader. I'm using tesseract 2

With this image, Terressact doesn't recognize anything and I don't know why :
[image: license plate not working]
Result : 100~

But if I use this one, it's ok :
[image: license plate working good]

here is my basic code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Code usage sample
        Ocr ocr = new Ocr();
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"D:\devs\abc\lpr\License_plate_Tirana.JPG"))
        {
            tessnet2.Tesseract tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
            tessocr.Init(null, "eng", false);
            tessocr.GetThresholdedImage(bmp, Rectangle.Empty).Save("D:\\devs\\abc\\lpr\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
            /* IMPORTANT !!!!!!!! => Tessdata directory must be in the directory than this exe*/
            Console.WriteLine("Multithread version");
            ocr.DoOCRMultiThred(bmp, "eng");
            //Console.WriteLine("Normal version");
            //ocr.DoOCRNormal(bmp, "eng");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: What is the indication of failure? Exception?

Comment: Nothing : Just Result : 100~ and exit code 0